# Передача аватарки из VK API в ImageView

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, bitmap, android-imageview

Как получить аватрку из VK API и передать её как `Bitmap` в [`ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)?

Comment: что именно не получается? получить ссылку на аватарку, или вывести изображение по ссылке в ImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аватарка - это адрес изображения, ссылка. Получите её сетевым запросом к API и скормите её к-л либе для загрузки/отображения картинок - Picasso, Glide

Ждя получения ссылки на изображение надо составить запрос согласно [описанию API](https://vk.com/dev/users.get)

Например: https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=1&fields=photo_100&v=5.53

Запрос вернёт JSON вида

```
{"response":[{"id":1,"first_name":"Павел","last_name":"Дуров","photo_100":"http:\/\/cs629231.vk.me\/v629231001\/c542\/fcMCbfjDsv0.jpg"}]}
```

В нём и лежит ссылка.

Доставать и парсить лучше всего Retrofit-ом

Comment: как получить адрес аватарки?

Comment: @head, дополнил ответ